# enum table C bind with int data table

Tags: c, enums, bind

Is there any way to bind enum data with an int table??
for example i have

```
enum Mode      { AUTO, COOL, DRY, HEAT, FAN };
unsigned int  modeMap[5] ;
```

And i was wondering if i could bind somehow the enum data with the corresponding in modemap table. I don't want to do it manually because i have more tables and it i don't want to write each one. i want to do something like

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(modeMap);i++)    
   Mode[i]=modeMap[i];
```

But that throws error. Is there any way to do what i want or do i have to do it manually?

EDIT
at run time i will have this

```
  modeMap[] = { 0x000010, 0x000000, 0x000020, 0x000030, 0x000020 };
```

so i want to have a line of code that assigns 0x000010 at AUTO, 0x000000 at COOl etc.

Comment: `sizeof(modeMap)` is `5 * sizeof(unsigned int)`, and `Mode[i]` invalid .

Comment: `for(i=0;i<sizeof(modeMap)/sizeof(*modeMap);++i) modeMap[i]=i;`

Comment: perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993142/

Comment: What do you mean by "bind"? Enumerations are compile-time constructs, it seems a bit like you want to "set" the numerical value of an enum symbol at run-time?

Comment: @unwind exactly and because i have a lot of tables i was wondering if i could do something different than auto = modeMap[0]; etc.

Comment: @arcanavk You can't do that *at all*, enum values are locked at compile-time.

Comment: @unwind i see ok thank you! i modified my code and i used switch instead to do my job.

Answer (score 0):

What you typically do when you want to name or keep track of the the indices of an array, is this:

```
typedef enum 
{ 
  AUTO, 
  COOL, 
  DRY, 
  HEAT, 
  FAN,

  MODES_N
} Mode;

unsigned int modeMap [MODES_N];

static_assert(MODES_N == sizeof(modeMap) / sizeof(*modeMap), 
              "Enum not consistent with array modeMap");

for(i=0; i<MODES_N; i++)    
  modeMap[i] = whatever;
```

Comment: i eddited my question because it was a bit unclear . i don;t want to assign values at modeMap but to nind theses values to enums

Comment: @arcanavk This is what this code does. `modeMap[AUTO]` will give you the value 0x000010. If you simply want the constant AUTO to be 0x000010, then just type `AUTO = 0x10,` in the enum declaration.